# Error when loading parameters into Symfony bundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I get following error:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for
> "upload_images" (in
> "/var/www/vhosts/diabetigraph-dev/vendor/verzeilberg/upload-images/src/Resources/services.yaml").
> Looked for namespace "upload_images", found "none"

This are my files:

**services.yaml**

```
services:
  verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\Service\Rotate:
    autowire: true

upload_images:
  version: 100
```

**Configuration**

```
namespace verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('upload_images');
        $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
                ->children()
                    ->integerNode('version')->end()
                ->end();
        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

**UploadImagesExtension**

```
namespace verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class UploadImagesExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(dirname(__DIR__).'/Resources'));
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
        $config = $this->processConfiguration(new Configuration(), $configs);
        $container->setParameter('version', $config['version']);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: most likely not even the problem, but why do you extend httpkernel's extension class and not `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension`? have you tried processing your config before loading the yaml? where did the error occur (stacktrace)

Comment: Are you sure you declared your bundle in the config/bundles.php file ?

Comment: This is the whole error: !!  In YamlFileLoader.php line 713:
!!                                                                                 
!!    There is no extension able to load the configuration for "upload_images" (i  
!!    n "/var/www/vhosts/diabetigraph-dev/vendor/verzeilberg/upload-images/src/Re  
!!    sources/services.yaml"). Looked for namespace "upload_images", found "none"


And yes I declared my bundle.

Comment: From your posted code it looks like you have upload_images in your services.yaml file?  That is just wrong.  You should have a config/packages/upload_images.yaml file and place you config code there for your UploadImagesBundle.  What is in upload_images.yaml will actually get passed to your Extension::load method as $configs.

Comment: But do you store config/packages/upload_images.yaml in your bundle folder or in root folder of symfony?

Comment: It always goes in the application's config/packages directory.  Nothing in the bundle itself.  That is really the whole point.  Allowing something external to config your bundle.  All the default configuration stuff goes in your Configuration class.

Comment: Then is it possible that I make default params for let say the upload folder. But the user can change this into his own folder. Or in a case where I define a default crop width and height and a user wants to change it to his own? 

I solved the error but stil can get the params in mine service class.

Comment: Yep and Yep.  You would set a default value for version in your Configuration class and then add the value as a parameter in Extension::load like you code is already doing.  You could then have it injected into a service using %version% though you might want to name it something like upload_images.version in your load method.  Configuration is so much fun.  It took me an embarrassing amount of time reading the docs over and over and experimenting before the concepts started to sink in.

Comment: In the tree builder I make the default values? But is it nesscesary that the upload_images.yaml file has to be saved in the application config/packages?

Can you point out some of those docs/tutorials?

Comment: It is all in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html).  Keep in mind that creating a shareable bundle requires a fair amount of Symfony knowledge.  And tutorials that you might come across will most likely be out of date as things have changed over the years.  Docs and examining other bundles such as the framework and security bundles are the best learning sources.  And yes, a bundle with an extension requires a configuration file at the application level.  If you setup defaults for everything then the file just needs a single line in it.  upload_images:

Comment: Thanks for your info going to check it out!

Comment: Do you feel like this pretty much answers your question?  If so I can provide an answer which summarizes the discussion.

Comment: This is indeed answer on my question thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic answer is that your upload_images configuration needs to be moved to it's own  application level config/packages file:

```
# app/config/packages/upload_images.yaml
upload_images:
  version: 100
```

In your bundle, the Configuration object represents the bundle's configuration.  There is no upload_images.yaml sort of file in your bundle.  The object is quite powerful so you can add defaults and options and what not.

Your bundle's extension takes care of processing the final configuration and making information such as parameters available to the rest of the system:

```
class UploadImagesExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // $configs is actually an array of array representing the contents of upload_files.yaml
        $config = $this->processConfiguration(new Configuration(), $configs);
        $container->setParameter('upload_files.version', $config['version']);

        // Loading your bundle's services.yaml file is a different process which just happens to be kicked off by the loader
        // Thanks to the setParameter above, %upload_files.version% can be used by services
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(dirname(__DIR__).'/Resources'));
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
    }
}
```

It can be confusing and for me at least I had to read the docs multiple times and do quite a bit of experimenting to understand the overall process.

The confusion is one of the reasons that Symfony evolved from multiple bundles per application to one application bundle to no application bundle at all.

I might also add the Symfony uses composer recipes to simplify installing a bundle.  The recipe not only adds the bundle to config/bundles.php but copies any default configuration file to config/packages as well.  Unfortunately, there are additional steps required for this copy to happen (see the docs) so it's easiest to do things the old-fashion way and just tell the developer to create the config file via the bundle's README file.

Comment: But how do I get the param (version) in my service class? I am getting this error: The parameter "version" must be defined.

Comment: Hard to know where to start.  Might be best to open another question.  Is your $container->setParameter('upload_files.version', $config['version']); statement being reached?