# How can I access config parameters defined in a custom extension?

Tags: symfony

I created a custom extension in my app for the sole purpose of being able to define config in yaml. I am unable to retrieve configuration params with `ParameterBagInterface`. What am I missing with the following approach?

config/packages/myapp.yaml

```
myapp:
  foo:
    bar: '%env(MYAPP_BAR)%'
```

I created a command to test if I could retrieve the config. When run, I get the error:

> The parameter "myapp" must be defined.

```
class FooCommand extends Command
{
    ...

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $params, $name = '')
    {
        $this->params = $params;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    ...

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        dd($this->params->get('myapp'));
        ...
```

I set all this up by creating the following files and modifying Kernel.php

- `src/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php`
- `src/DependencyInjection/MyappExtension.php`

Note that in the extension file below, the `dd($config)` prints everything defined in `myapp.yaml`.

src/DependencyInjection/MyappExtension.php

```
class MyappExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        // This dumps my config as an array
        // dd($config);
    }
}
```

src/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('myapp');

        $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('foo')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('bar')->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
```

src/Kernel.php (1 line modification)

```
...
    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader): void
    {
        $container->addResource(new FileResource($this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php'));
        $container->registerExtension(new MyappExtension());
        ...
```

Comment: Is `config/packages/myapp.yaml` the actual content of the file?

Comment: You are almost there.  Just need to explicitly create the parameter in your extension.  I know it may seem like whatever is in myapp.yaml should be automatically parameterized but that is not what happens.  Basically add: $container->setParameter('myapp', $config['myapp']);  [More detailed example is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63409920/error-when-loading-parameters-into-symfony-bundle/63425914#63425914).

Comment: Wow, 1 line away! :) Confirmed, adding `$container->setParameter('myapp', $config);` to `MyappExtension.php` resolved it. I can see the advantage here in having a place to pre-process config as well. Thank you @Cerad.